# How to apply online for a transit UAE visa?

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, uae, emirates

[The official UAE government site](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visit-visas/transit-visa) states that:

> The UAE issues two types of transit visas: one for 48 hours which is **free of charge**, and another for 96 hours for AED 50 only. Transit visas are sponsored only by the UAE-based airlines and must be processed and approved before entering the UAE.

However, their links are confusing:

- [Link to Transit visa from Etihad Airways - Etihad Airways](https://www.etihad.com/en-ae/fly-etihad/visas) states "Visa fee: AED 37", which is admittedly not a large amount but still not free as claimed by the government page. For that fee, it seems to work though (I haven't followed all steps) but **the entry can only be Abu Dhabi**, not Dubai.
- [Link to Transit visa from Emirates Airline - Emirates Airline](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/) is not showing any link to apply seemingly, giving instead "UAE Visa Information. Everything you need to know about UAE visas and sponsorship." But I can't find the most important information -- the link to apply!

Searching for visa requirements for Thai citizens leads to [this page](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-uae-visa-requirements/?nationality=th&destination=ae) giving the following information:

> Visa

> Visa required.

> Visa Issuance:

> E-visas can be obtained before departure at [https://smart.gdrfad.gov.ae/HomePage.aspx﻿](https://smart.gdrfad.gov.ae/HomePage.aspx%EF%BB%BF) (for Dubai) or [https://smartservices.ica.gov.ae/echannels/web/client/default.html#/login﻿](https://smartservices.ica.gov.ae/echannels/web/client/default.html#/login%EF%BB%BF) (for other emirates). Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation.

Confusingly, the link for Dubai still does not show any link to apply for a transit UAE visa for a foreigner. This information is nowhere to be found as far as I could see.

So, how can I apply online for a transit visa to visit Dubai with Thai citizenship?

I don't mind paying a small fee, just need a webpage that works and delivers the result.

Comment: Do you fly with Emirates?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella This is a possiblity.

Answer (score 7):

[Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/) states

> Apply online through Manage your booking

> This service is only available to passengers with a confirmed Emirates booking where an Emirates ticket has already been issued and the flight itinerary already includes the desired time in Dubai. The itinerary into and out of Dubai should be on one ticket (PNR), and these flights must be Emirates flights. Note that any itineraries including any flights to or from Dubai on other carriers are not eligible for the online visa service.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any official information from Emirates confirming that such an application is possible fully online after the flight is booked? I am worried to book and then to find out the process is more complicated, e.g. involving going to the Embassy. Or what if the visa is not granted? Is the ticket fully refunded?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/) 
"If you are travelling to or stopping over in Dubai with Emirates, you can submit an application and receive your UAE visa entirely online – without having to submit your passport for stamping"

Comment: This is the page I mentioned in my question and it does not say that visa can be applied online through Manage your booking.